# Create a Line chart using highcharts.js inside a tab with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts, ng-show

I am creating a web app with multiple tabs in a page. In one of the tabs using ng-show, I am willing to show a Line chart using highcharts.

I have a JavaScript file for the app where based on the selection of multiple html templates i have, the controllers for each html template are being defined.

For the JavaScript part of the chart, when I try to include the code in the file the app stops working. I then tried using the *$scope.configChart = {...}* inside the controller, but it also results into the same thing.

Can anyone help me with, how exactly should I implement the chart using highcharts. Apologies for this, may be this is a naive question but I am new to AngularJS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for our understanding of your problem, if you could please post your code. The possibilities might be your view is not binding with the $scope object or function call is misplaced in the code(order of execution)